# Why select count(*) from table_name is so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```sql
mysql> select count(*)
    -> from ip_address_varchar20;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2764687 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 28.80 sec)
```

I thought there should be a field to store the size of any table, but I find that count(*） is so slow.

Why DBMS do not optimize this? Or I do some bad practice on this?

Comment: What is the DB Engine (e.g. InnoDB)? Is the DB server busy? What is the data type? Are there any indexes added in the table? Normally `COUNT(*)` won't take so long.

Comment: @Raptor InnoDB, not busy, a int column and varchar(20) column, only one index on int column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Why_PostgreSQL_Instead_of_MySQL:_Comparing_Reliability_and_Speed_in_2007

> One operation that PostgreSQL is known to be slow performing is doing
>   a full count of rows in a table, typically using this SQL:
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
>
> The reason why this is slow is related to the MVCC implementation in
>   PostgreSQL. The fact that multiple transactions can see different
>   states of the data means that there can be no straightforward way for
>   "COUNT(*)" to summarize data across the whole table; PostgreSQL must
>   walk through all rows, in some sense. This normally results in a
>   sequential scan reading information about every row in the table.

The explanation above for Postgres applies to MySQL's InnoDB as well. As InnoDB uses MVCC.

There are some [approaches](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql%20innodb%20fast%20count) to do fast count with InnoDB. E.g., You can use estimate, or you can use triggers to maintain the table's row count.

Answer (score -1):

Some databases do store the size of a table externally.  However, most databases read all the data -- either directly or through an index -- in order to satisfy a `COUNT()` query.

This ensures that the rows are accurately counted.  It also takes transactional semantics into account.

Comment: @tdjprog . . . For example, Google BigQuery does, and uses the values for `count(*)` queries.  SQL Server stores the information -- or at least a *very* close approximation -- but this is only in metadata tables and not used for other queries.